# Как получить значение из json массива (многомерный)

Tags: php, json

Мои знания не позволяют мне это сделать.
У меня есть массив: [МАССИВ](https://pastebin.com/q2RgpBrB)

Надо получить все значение alias и к ним amount
Мне надо что бы на выводе получилось примерно так:
[![rub - 1 
usd - 0.01][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fMpB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fMpB.png)

Помогите пожалуйста мне

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array();
foreach($your_array['accounts'] as $v){
   $result[] = str_replace("qw_wallet_","",$v["alias"]) . " - " . $v["balance"]    ["amount"];
}
echo join(", ",$result);
```

Comment: Не работает. Просто выводит "-"

Comment: попробуй исправленный вариант